# Keras Categorical_crossentropy loss implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to reimplement the Categorical Cross Entropy loss from Keras so that I can customize it. I got the following

```
def CustomCrossEntropy(output, target, axis=-1):
    target = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(target)
    output = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(output)
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
    output = output / math_ops.reduce_sum(output, axis, True)
    # Compute cross entropy from probabilities.
    epsilon_ = _constant_to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)
    return -math_ops.reduce_sum(target * math_ops.log(output), axis)
```

It produces different results than the internal function which confuses me, as I just copied the code from [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py) so far. What am I missing here?

Prove:

```
y_true = [[0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
customLoss = CustomCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred)
assert loss.shape == (2,)
print(loss)
print(customLoss)
>>tf.Tensor([0.05129331 2.3025851 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
>>tf.Tensor([ 0.8059049 14.506287 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: `0.9843` vs. `0.9885` is a pretty small change in accuracy, small enough to be due to variance. Are these results produced on the same random number seed?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes train loss: `0.2714` vs `0.0338`, val_loss: `0.1857` vs `0.0299`. This is what confused me and is a big different imo, isnt it?

Comment: I think this question is asking about the difference between loss vs. model performance, which is more of a theoretical question. [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39825/log-loss-vs-accuracy-for-deciding-between-different-learning-rates) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258166/good-accuracy-despite-high-loss-value) might better answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inverted the arguments of the function in your definition of `CustomCrossEntropy`, if you double check the source code in GitHub you will see that the first argument is `target` and the second one is `output`. If you switch them back you will get the same results as expected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.backend import categorical_crossentropy as CustomCrossEntropy

y_true = [[0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]

y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)

loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss)
# tf.Tensor([0.05129331 2.3025851 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)

loss = CustomCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss)
# tf.Tensor([0.05129331 2.3025851 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)

loss = CustomCrossEntropy(y_pred, y_true)
print(loss)
# tf.Tensor([ 0.8059049 14.506287 ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```